# Subdivision surface modifier shows strange results on my model in some places

Tags: modeling, rigging, subdivision-surface, shape-keys

I am currently rigging my model and trying to improve it with shape keys. But as soon as I turn on the subdivision surface modifier, a strange result comes out at this position. Do you have any idea what I can do?

[image]

[image]

No subdivision surface modifier...

[image]

With subdivision surface modifier...

[image]
[image]

Example:
No subdivision surface modifier...
[image]

With subdivision surface modifier...
[image]

Comment: Hello, what is the strange result you're talking about? can you please be more specific?

Comment: As soon as I turn on this subdivision surface modifier, the area I am working on deforms. I will post more detailed pictures so you understand what my problem is.

Comment: Catmull clark subdivision fills in the blanks-- deforms the mesh.  If you don't want that, use simple subdivision instead.  General rules for getting smooth surfaces from CC subdiv are to use all quad meshes made up of planar, square (aspect+angle) quads-- no tris-- with no 6+ poles and no non-planar 3 or 5 poles.  Your meshes do not meet those criteria very well.